Conway A first course in analysis Proposition 7.1.4

I am having a heck of a time understanding the proof of this proposition. In particular, I struggle to see how Conway got to line 7.1.5 included in the picture below. I follow the first paragraph until the final sentence. The final sentence I understand expect for why those inequalities were chosen and how 7.1.5 was conclude.

Hope someone can help because I am trying work through at least this chapter of the book, but I took analysis awhile ago

As a heads up, the site moderators don't like it when people post essential information pertaining to a question in their posts. Just be weary of this. (They can be a little aggressive on here.)

@JAG131 Thanks for the heads up though I don't quite follow what you mean by "essential information pertaining to a question in their posts"? Like in reference to the title or the screenshots?

Sorry, I just realized I completely forgot to add a word to my comment: Screenshot. You can't post essential information via screenshots on posts here.

Use MathJax to add information, not an image.

And boldface always looks like shouting. This scares some readers away, and they won't read further. Here is a
tutorial for MathJax.


You need $t_i-t_{i-1}<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt p}$ for $|t-t'|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt p}$ for all $t,t'\in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ and therefore
$$\left\|(t,\dots,t)-(t',\dots,t')\right\|=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^p|t-{t'}|^2}<\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^p\frac{\delta^2}{p}}=\delta.$$ This yields \begin{equation}|F(t,\dots,t)-F(t',\dots,t')|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}\label{gl1}\tag{1}\end{equation} for all $t,t'\in [t_{i-1},t_i]$
And you want to apply the MVT (integral version), i.e. there are $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ with $\xi_i\in(t_{i-1},t_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ with
\begin{equation}\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}F(x,\dots,x)\;\text dx=F(\xi_i,\dots,\xi_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})\label{gl2}\tag{2}\end{equation} with the use of the continuous (univariate) function $G(t):=F(t,\dots,t)$, $t\in [a,b]$.
For your eq 7.1.5 you compute:
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^b\left\|\gamma^{\prime}(t)\right\| d t-\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|\gamma^{\prime}\left(t_i\right)\right\|\left(t_i-t_{i-1}\right)\right|&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\left|\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}F(t,\dots,t)\; d t-F(t_i,\dots,t_i)\left(t_i-t_{i-1}\right)\right|\\
&\overset{\eqref{gl2}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|F(\xi_i˛\dots,\xi_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})-F(t_i,\dots,t_i)\left(t_i-t_{i-1}\right)\right|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n|F(\xi_i,\dots,\xi_i)-F(t_i,\dots,t_i)|(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
&\overset{\eqref{gl1}}{<}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
&=\frac\epsilon2
\end{align}
I hope this helps.


Thanks! 1) was extremely helpful, and 2) I thought had to be the case but the way he words the next paragraph made me think it wasn’t. I’ll need to write out 3) tomorrow. Thanks again!
